Flutter web reduce Largest Contentful Paint element
Currently asset image slow down first load of flutter web page.

Image referenced are displayed using simple Image.asset under sizedbox
SizedBox(
  height: width * icon,
  child: Image.asset("assets/other/cb_logo.webp"),
),

I've attempt to reduce load delay by implementing precacheimage, uploading it to firebasestorage and use it under CachedNetworkImage and more but nothing seem to make changed to load delay.
Please teach me I can reduce the LCP of flutter web.
